# Write the else if block with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

How can I write the else if block with condition with the usepackage `algorithm2e`?

I want to write the following with the `algorithm2e` package:

```
if(condition){
  //code
 }else if(condition){
  // code
 }else{
  //code
 }
```

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,t1enc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%Header part
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\cfoot{center of the footer!}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%pseudocode.
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%blacksquare
\usepackage{ amssymb }

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}[H]


function search(v,w,s) \\
   binarsearch(v,w,s,0, |w|) \\

   binarsearch(v,w,s,l, r) \\

   \If{$v$ prefix of $w_s[m]$}{
      return true;
   }\ElseIf(elseif comment){
                           binarsearch(v,w,s,l,m-1)
                           }  
\caption{}
\label{alg: initializer}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 55):

To combine such conditions, write each as a separate component using `\uIf` and `\uElseIf` (and `\uElse`, if needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \uIf{if condition}{
    something if \;
  }
  \uElseIf{elseif condition}{
    something elseif \;
  }
  \Else{
    something else \;
  }
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```